# Flurry CN1Lib error after submitting Android build

Tags: java, gradle, codenameone

I am getting error '*Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/ec2-user/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2*' when submitting an Android build request.

I suspect it has got to do with **Flurry CN1Lib**

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --verbose --force-jumbo --num-threads=4 --output
```

Comment: Can you include the full log? Notice that if you're using IntelliJ IDEA you need to switch to text mode as explained here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-intellij-idea-ram.html

Comment: Here it is on Google Drive - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y3o1kvze4vFjgYb92ve51bdysOgl2trY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally managed to fix this issue. I was only interested on getting the analytics bit working but I believe Ads should work too. Here is how I did it:

1. Cloned/downloaded the current CN1Flurry project from GitHub here https://github.com/chen-fishbein/flurry-codenameone. This allowed me to access the source files and use them for reference.
2. Importing the project as is into my Netbeans was bringing some 'resolve project' issues so I just went ahead and created a new project with similar name and package/class structure as CN1Flurry then copied classes from old project into the new one.
3. Open the `FlurryNative` class and delete the `onPageView()`, `setLogEvents()` and `setCrashReportingEnabled()` as these aren't supported by current Flurry Android SDK. Once done, right-click on the `FlurryNative` class and choose 'Generate Native Access'. This will allow you to create native implementations for Android, iOS, Windows etc in the 'native' folder of the project.
4. Chen's project uses version 5.3.0 of Flurry SDKs but the recommended SDK version is version 12.1.0. Download the latest aar files from your Flurry portal under the 'Admin' section and copy them to the 'android' folder. For me these were `flurryAds_12.1.0.aar` and `flurryAnalytics_12.1.0.aar`
5. Switch to the `Files` view of your Netbeans project and open the `FlurryNativeImpl` class. You can copy most of the implementations from Chen's project the only thing you need to change is the `initFlurry()` method to -  `new FlurryAgent.Builder().build(AndroidNativeUtil.getActivity(), apiKey);` Flurry is initialized differently in the new SDK  - https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android/
6. That's it. Switch back to the 'Projects' view then clean and build your CN1Flurry project to generate the .cn1lib file which you can then add to your UI project in the 'libs' folder. Remember to refresh cn1Libs files.

Finally, add the following build hints to your UI project:

```
android.min_sdk_version=16
android.multidex=true
android.xapplication=\<activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryFullscreenTakeoverActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"> \</activity>
```

Chen suggests a whole lot of other build hints to add but I didn't find them useful for my case.

Still learning the ropes on how GitHub works; will make a pull request once I get comfortable. Meanwhile, you can get the entire project here - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GGygaVelmMhMUX9Deik9W72hXkw_detG

Answer (score 0):

The flurry cn1lib needs to be updated to use the newer Android API level 28 for location which is our current default. That's the right thing to do for the long term.

As a short term patch you might be able to define: `android.playServicesVersion=8.3.0` in the build hints to work around this. Notice that this might impact the functionality of your app such as location services support etc.

Comment: android.playServicesVersion=8.3.0 didn't work. Build still failed. Any idea when the lib will be patched?

Comment: I'm not sure when we'll get around to do that.